# Scheduling GPU resources using the Sun Grid Engine (SGE)

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, sungridengine, multiple-gpu

We have a cluster of machines, each with 4 GPUs.  Each job should be able to ask for 1-4 GPUs.  Here's the catch: I would like the SGE to tell each job *which* GPU(s) it should take.  Unlike the CPU, a GPU works best if only one process accesses it at a time.  So I would like to:

```
Job #1  GPU: 0, 1, 3
Job #2  GPU: 2
Job #4  wait until 1-4 GPUs are avaliable
```

The problem I've run into, is that the SGE will let me create a GPU resource with 4 units on each node, but it won't explicitly tell a job which GPU to use (only that it gets 1, or 3, or whatever).

I thought of creating 4 resources (`gpu0, gpu1, gpu2, gpu3`), but am not sure if the `-l` flag will take a glob pattern, and can't figure out how the SGE would tell the job which gpu resources it received.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have multiple GPUs and you want your jobs to request a GPU but the Grid Engine scheduler should handle and select a *free* GPUs you can configure a RSMAP (resource map) complex (instead of a INT). This allows you to specify the amount as well as the names of the GPUs on a specific host in the host configuration. You can also set it up as a HOST consumable, so that independent of the slots your request, the amount of GPU devices requested with -l cuda=2 is for each host 2 (even if the parallel job got i.e. 8 slots on different hosts).

```
qconf -mc
    #name               shortcut   type        relop   requestable consumable default  urgency     
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    gpu                 gpu        RSMAP         <=      YES         HOST        0        0
```

In the execution host configuration you can initialize your resources with ids/names (here simply GPU1 and GPU2).

```
qconf -me yourhost
hostname              yourhost
load_scaling          NONE
complex_values        gpu=2(GPU1 GPU2)
```

Then when requesting -l gpu=1 the Univa Grid Engine scheduler will select GPU2 if GPU1 is already used by a different job. You can see the actual selection in the qstat -j output. The job gets the selected GPU by reading out the $SGE_HGR_gpu environment variable, which contains in this case the chose id/name "GPU2". This can be used for accessing the right GPU without having collisions.

If you have a multi-socket host you can even attach a GPU directly to some CPU cores near the GPU (near the PCIe bus) in order to speed up communication between GPU and CPUs. This is possible by attaching a topology mask in the execution host configuration.

```
qconf -me yourhost
hostname              yourhost
load_scaling          NONE
complex_values        gpu=2(GPU1:SCCCCScccc GPU2:SccccSCCCC)
```

Now when the UGE scheduler selects GPU2 it automatically binds the job to all 4 cores (C) of the second socket (S) so that the job is not allowed to run on the first socket. This does not even require the -binding qsub param.

More configuration examples you can find on [www.gridengine.eu](http://www.gridengine.eu).

Note, that all these features are only available in Univa Grid Engine (8.1.0/8.1.3 and higher), and not in SGE 6.2u5 and other Grid Engine version (like OGE, Sun of Grid Engine etc.). You can try it out by downloading the 48-core limited free version from univa.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the other grid engine variants you can try adapting the scripts we use on our cluster:
https://github.com/UCL/Grid-Engine-Prolog-Scripts